# Memory leak in iOS app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

[image: Call Trace][image: Leaks]I am trying to trace the memory leaks in my app. I have used the Leak template on Instrument. While doing Call Tree, I have selected "Hide System Libraries", I only see:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

as the code with issue, which I am not sure if is correct. Most of the memory leaks are in `UIKit`, `CoreFoundation` and Malloc Blocks.

Is it possible to fix those system libraries issue.

[image: Memory Leak Debug]

I have not done much memory testing myself, so I will appreciate if someone can help me figure out how can go ahead if I can fix those issues.

Comment: Your screenshot is from Xcode, not Instruments. Show the screenshot of the Instruments call tree. I can tell you the main function is not the cause of your memory leak. Inverting the call tree can also help you find your code in the call tree.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I edited the question with Leaks and call trace. Thank you